WiFi/Bluetooth trapped in a 125B Enclosure
I plan to design a PCB where I would put my ESP32 and associated WiFi and Bluetooth in a 125B enclosure for a guitar pedal project. The enclosure is made of metal, and the electronics would be in there.
I plan to use WiFi and Bluetooth to control the parameters of the system, and I was wondering how bad it would be to entrap the WiFi/Bluetooth like this.
My goal is to control the device from within 5 meters, not from across the room, so my requirements are not very strict. Still, I would like to ask how badly the 125B would affect the wireless communication.

what is preventing you from running a test?

This is sort of the opposite of an EMC problem.  In that scenario, you are (usually) trying to achieve a certain amount of attenuation (dB) across a range of frequencies.  In your case, you want to guarantee an attenuation of no more the XX dB.  I've never had to deal with this type of issue.

If you are doing this strictly for your own personal one-off usage then the concept to make this work is to plan on modifying the enclosure so that it has open windows to the WiFi and BlueTooth antennas on the ESP-32 module. This may require careful packaging design to position said antennas in the proper orientation with respect to the open windows in the enclosure.
If you had any concept for trying to productize this and start selling equipment beyond limited range personal usage then there would be a whole different design strategy required and its attendant agency regulation and requirements testing.

Hello ! Thanks for answering. I'll see if I can figure out how to do what you've described. I think jsotola's comment of my original post is also fair: I guess I could just try and cross my fingers that it works well enough.
